# Proof of limit of the function $x^2+x+5$ at $x=5$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

There's a specific type of function that I find always tricky when proving continuity, specifically when we have to bound the free variable. I noticed this initially with the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, where picking delta is not as easy as it seems. I came across another example today that seemed really easy and sort of employed the same technique used in the $\frac{1}{x}$ proof. I just want to clarify some things about this.

> Consider $f(x)=x^2+x+5$, prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 5}f(x)=35$

I began like all of my other limit proofs with some scratch work to find delta:

\begin{align}
|f(x)-35|\\
\implies|x^2+x+5-35|\\
\implies|x^2+x-30|\\
\implies|x-5||x+6|<\epsilon
\end{align}

Clearly $|x-5|<\delta$ from our assumption in the definition. The problem is the bounding of $|x+6|$. In the solutions I have provided is s.t. we allow $\delta\leq 1$ and then find that $|x-5|<\delta\implies-\delta<x-5<\delta\implies|x+6|\leq12$, thus bounding $|x+6|$ and allowing us to finish the proof. In the formal proof, we consider both the $\delta=1$ and $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{12}$ in the form of :$\delta = min{1,\frac{\epsilon}{12}$.

To me, this choice of delta seems completely arbitrary and without motive. How can we simply choose delta to be something if in the definition we say "$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta...$"? Also, how does the case of $\delta=1$ hold when performing the formal proof? For instance:

\begin{align}
|f(x)-35|...\\
|x-5||x+6|<\delta\cdot 12=1\cdot 12=\epsilon???
\end{align}

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We can choose $\delta$ precisely *because* it reads "$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$"; we just have to show one exists. We don't have to find one that's maximal or otherwise elegant.

Comment: To your second question: The case of $\delta = 1$ only holds when we are given $\varepsilon \geq 12$. Otherwise, $\varepsilon/12$ is smaller and holds sway.

Comment: Use `\cdot` for multiplication in equations rather than `*`.

Comment: I see. So in general when we wish to find a bound of the free variable (in this case x), we can "fix" a delta allowing us to find a bound for x, which in turn allows us to continue along the with the proof (in this case having the choice that $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{12}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that there is a degree of arbitrariness in which particular rule you come up with for $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$.

It's kind of like a woodworkers jig that holds your pieces in the correct position while you connect them. Two different carpenters might come up with different jigs for the same job, but in the end they throw away the jig and are left with the same piece.

Similarly, two mathematicians might come up with different rules for $\delta$, but in the end they have the same value for the limit. (You probably breezed by a proof that limits, if they exist, are unique. I'm relying on that theorem in that last sentence.) So, like with making a jig, you can just do what you find convenient, so long as it gets the job done.

As for "without motive", sometimes that's true. In the case of your quadratic function, note that proving

$$ |\text{thing}| \le 2 * \varepsilon \,\,\,\,\forall  \varepsilon \gt 0$$

ends up with the same conclusion as

$$ |\text{thing}| \le 1,000,000,000 * \varepsilon \,\,\,\,\forall  \varepsilon \gt 0,$$

all that matters is that we can get some constant (that is independent of $x$ in some neighborhood of $x$) in there. You could cap your $\delta$ with a 1, or a 2, or a 10, and the only difference would be the size of that constant. (Although it is pretty common, almost a tradition, to pick 1. I think it's because 1 is seen as very not-special. "It doesn't matter what I pick? Okay, let's just go with 1 then - why complicate things?")

But in the case of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, the motive is crystal clear - we want to keep $x$ away from $0$, where things get messy. So for that function your rule for $\delta$ is going to include something that keeps $x$ away from $0$.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider $f(x)=x^2+x+5$, prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 5}f(x)=35$

My $~\epsilon,\delta~$ approach to such a problem is to forgo elegance.

$\underline{\text{Preliminary Results}}$

- For $0 < a,~$ you have that 
  $~|f(x)| < a \iff -a < f(x) < a.~$
- I like to keep things linear.  My standard approach here is to impose the additional constraint on $~\delta~$ that (positive) $~\delta \leq \dfrac{1}{10}.$ 
  This implies that $~\delta^2 \leq \dfrac{\delta}{10}.$

---

Set $~f(x) = x^2 + x + 5.$

**To Prove:**

$\forall ~\epsilon > 0, ~\exists ~\delta > 0,~$ such that

$$0 < |x - 5| < \delta \tag1 $$

implies

$$|f(x) - f(5)| < \epsilon. \tag2 $$

---

(1) above can be re-expressed as

$$-\delta < x - 5 < \delta \iff 5 - \delta < x < 5 + \delta. \tag3 $$

Add the additional constraint:

$$\delta \leq \dfrac{1}{10}. \tag4 $$

(2) above can be re-expressed as

$$ -\epsilon < f(x) - f(5) = x^2 + x - 30 < \epsilon \iff $$

$$30 - \epsilon < x^2 + x < 30 + \epsilon. \tag5 $$

So, the problem has been reduced to establishing a relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon~$ so that (3) and (4) above collectively imply (5) above.

---

Since $~\delta~$ is small, you know that 
$5 - \delta~$ and $~5 + \delta~$ are both positive.

Therefore, you have that 
$(5 - \delta)^2 < x^2 < (5 + \delta)^2 \iff $ 
$25 - 10 \delta + \delta^2 < x^2 < 25 + 10\delta + \delta ^2.$

Since $~\delta^2 \leq \dfrac{\delta}{10},~$ you can conclude that 
$25 - 11 \delta < x^2 < 25 + 11\delta.$

You also have from (3) above that 
$5 - \delta < x < 5 + \delta.$

Putting these two conclusions together, you have that 
$30 - 12\delta < x^2 + x < 30 + 12\delta.$

Given the requirement in (5) above, 
you simply need for $~12\delta~$ to be $~\leq \epsilon.$

So, specify:

$$\delta = \min\left[ ~\frac{\epsilon}{12}, ~\frac{1}{10} ~\right].$$

Comment: elegant solution, thank you!